# jQuery select only the element with $(this)

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using a bit of code to slidetoggle `ul`:s in form of an hierarchy. Foreach click on a `li` containing a `ul` the `ul` should slidetoggle. I'm trying to use `$(this)` to select the element that has been clicked, but instead it chooses all the elements using the same class.
How should I write my code to make it only choose one element?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list").click(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Code looks correct?? what error are you getting??

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and show us you html.... `this` should be the element.

Comment: No error, but instead of slidetoggling the elements child ul it slidetoggles all ul-childs of elements using the ".list"-class

Comment: @user3202738, Could you publish the `html code` ?

Comment: Of course, http://jsfiddle.net/Tz85y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused because a click in a children element is also a click in the parent, it proc multiple events.

You can prevent that with `e.stopPropagation` but you also need to change your selector. Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nestedlist li").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tz85y/1/

Comment: Karl, I've removed my answer, because yours is the better one.